How to reintegrate my users from a backup to a new system fresh installed?
I have had to reinstall my system - it is a Debian but my question addresses any distribution. I have disconnected the hard drive where my /homeis settled to avoid any risk when reinstalling the system where I have created a different user.
Now, I have reconnected my /home disk, what is the correct way to integrate it to the system with all my users?
Can I do simply:

Update fstab to mount /home on this disk (the /home from the new installation would be hidden but this is ok for me)
Copy my users groups lines from my backup of /etc/passwd and /etc/group

Or are there some more complex things that require to redeclare them with adduser & addgroup?
